# Processing Conflict: mysql55w-libs-5.5.36-3.w6.x86_64 conflicts mysql-libs < 5.5

Tags: mysql, centos6

I'm trying to install the latest webtatic MySQL 5.5 edition via yum (http://webtatic.com/packages/mysql55/) on CentOS 6.5 but every time I try I get the following output ending in error:

```
# yum install mysql55w mysql55w-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql55w.x86_64 0:5.5.36-3.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql55w-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.36-3.w6 for package: mysql55w-5.5.36-3.w6.x86_64
---> Package mysql55w-server.x86_64 0:5.5.36-3.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBI for package: mysql55w-server-5.5.36-3.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL for package: mysql55w-server-5.5.36-3.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: mysql55w-server-5.5.36-3.w6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql55w-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.36-3.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient16 for package: mysql55w-libs-5.5.36-3.w6.x86_64
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:4.013-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-DBI.x86_64 0:1.609-4.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmysqlclient16.x86_64 0:5.1.69-1.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: mysql55w-libs-5.5.36-3.w6.x86_64 conflicts mysql-libs < 5.5
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mysql55w-libs conflicts with mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
```

Considered running `yum remove mysql-libs` but that removes a lot of other dependencies that I'm pretty sure will cause me some problems:

```
Removing:
 mysql-libs                                   x86_64                              5.1.73-3.el6_5                                  @updates
Removing for dependencies:
 cloud-init                                   noarch                              0.7.4-2.el6                                     @epel/6.5
 cronie                                       x86_64                              1.4.4-12.el6                                    @anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5
 cronie-anacron                               x86_64                              1.4.4-12.el6                                    @anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5
 crontabs                                     noarch                              1.10-33.el6                                     @anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5
 php55w-mysql                                 x86_64                              5.5.10-1.w6                                     @webtatic
 postfix                                      x86_64                              2:2.6.6-6.el6_5                                 @updates
 redhat-lsb-core                              x86_64                              4.0-7.el6.centos                                @anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5
```

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can resolve it by switching the mysql-libs package to mysql55w-libs. This needs to be done in one transaction to avoid it uninstalling the other dependencies:

```
yum install yum-plugin-replace
yum replace mysql-libs --replace-with mysql55w-libs

yum install mysql55w mysql55w-server
```

Comment: I got the following error when I did the replace command. Should I be bothered? `WARNING: Unable to resolve all providers: ['config(mysql-libs)', 'libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)', 'libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)', 'libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)', 'libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)']`

Comment: It can sometimes signify something wrong, but if you confirm it, you'll see the packages being installed and uninstalled, so that will be more familiar to you to see whether things like postfix is unintentially being uninstalled