# Mysql conflicts on Centos 6.7

Tags: centos, mysql, centos6

I am trying trying to install RMySQL on Centos 6.7 however I am not very experienced with server stuff so bear with me. I use this command

```
sudo yum install mysql-devel
```

However I keep getting the following output

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-devel.x86_64 0:5.1.73-5.el6_7.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql = 5.1.73-5.el6_7.1 for package: mysql-devel-5.1.73-5.el6_7.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.73-5.el6_7.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-libs = 5.1.73-5.el6_7.1 for package: mysql-5.1.73-5.el6_7.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.73-5.el6_7.1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: mysql55w-5.5.47-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts mysql < 5.5
--> Processing Conflict: mysql55w-libs-5.5.47-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts mysql-libs < 5.5
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mysql55w-libs conflicts with mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_7.1.x86_64
Error: mysql55w conflicts with mysql-5.1.73-5.el6_7.1.x86_64
```

Now I assumed I had to replace the package so I tried the solution present here

```
yum install yum-plugin-replace

yum replace mysql-libs --replace-with mysql55w-libs

yum install mysql55w mysql55w-server
```

([Processing Conflict: mysql55w-libs-5.5.36-3.w6.x86_64 conflicts mysql-libs < 5.5](https://serverfault.com/questions/588078/processing-conflict-mysql55w-libs-5-5-36-3-w6-x86-64-conflicts-mysql-libs-5-5))

However I get that  "Package 'mysql-libs' is not installed" message, even when I use the exact version name (mysql-5.1.73-5.el6_7.1.x86_64)

Anyone has any tip about how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed `mysql55w` and `mysql55w-libs` from a [third-party repository](https://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/), probably to get version 5.5, but those packages conflict with the standard `mysql-devel` package provided by CentOS, which is at version 5.1. You likely need to find the equivalent `-devel` package from the third-party repository. Try installing `mysql55w-devel` instead of `mysql-devel`.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed it was something like that but not entirely sure how to fix it. Turns out it was way simpler than I thought.